# Need to modify this 301 Redirect code to support old HTML page(s) name to new ASP Page(s) name

Tags: redirect, asp-classic

I am a cut and paste NON Programmer. I can't even spell ASP or HTML.  So I asked my friends at Microsoft to write the following code for me and it is working fine so far.  But now my friends at Microsoft are no longer available and I need to modify this code to support entering an old page name and redirecting it to the new page name (and directory if needed).  I want to be able to specify the old page name in the code and have the code give me a 301 redirect to the new page name I specify in the code.

Can anyone write the modification for me and allow me to cut and paste it into my include file?  Here's the code for the existing include file...

```
<%
Dim serverName 
serverName = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")

Dim redirectUrl
redirectUrl = "/domains4sale.asp"

Dim canRedirect 
canRedirect = "False"

Dim hostNameArray(14) 'Array of host name

hostNameArray(0) = "bananapages.net"
hostNameArray(1) = "www.bananapages.net"
hostNameArray(2) = "6379100.com"
hostNameArray(3) = "www.6379100.com"
hostNameArray(4) = "caribbeanexhibits.com"
hostNameArray(5) = "www.caribbeanexhibits.com"
hostNameArray(6) = "caribbeanspecialevents.com"
hostNameArray(7) = "www.caribbeanspecialevents.com"
hostNameArray(8) = "caribeexpo.com"
hostNameArray(9) = "www.caribeexpo.com"
hostNameArray(10) = "daleallenenterprises.com"
hostNameArray(11) = "www.daleallenenterprises.com"
hostNameArray(12) = "rrcpapsc.com"
hostNameArray(13) = "www.rrcpapsc.com"
hostNameArray(14) = "daleallen.com"


If serverName = "www.daleallen.com" Then
     redirectUrl = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL")
     If Cint(InStr(redirectUrl, "/2010-website/")) >= 1 Then
        canRedirect = "True"
        redirectUrl = Replace(redirectUrl, "/2010-website/", "/")
    End If 
Else
    For Each item In hostNameArray
     If serverName = item  Then
        serverName = "www.daleallen.com"
        canRedirect = "True"
        If(item = "daleallen.com") Then
            redirectUrl = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL") 
            redirectUrl = Replace(redirectUrl, "/2010-website/", "/")
        End If      
        Exit For
     End If
    Next

End If

If canRedirect = "True" Then
    Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
    If Request.QueryString <> "" Then
      Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://" & serverName & redirectUrl & "?"     &           Request.QueryString  
    Else
        Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://" & serverName & redirectUrl 
    End If 
End If 
%>
```

Comment: We're not actually here to write your code for you, I'm afraid.  If you ask questions about things you don't understand then we may be able to give you answers to help you resolve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Start with these lines from your original code

```
If Cint(InStr(redirectUrl, "/2010-website/")) >= 1 Then
    canRedirect = "True"
    redirectUrl = Replace(redirectUrl, "/2010-website/", "/")
End If
```

You need to add something similar immediately after it - eg

```
If Cint(InStr(redirectUrl, "yourolddirectory/youroldfilename.html")) >= 1 Then
    canRedirect = "True"
    redirectUrl = Replace(redirectUrl, "yourolddirectory/youroldfilename.html", "yournewdirectory/yournewfilename.html")
End If
```

Comment: Well John:  I tried your code and it does not give me an error but it does not work either.   Perhaps you would consider logging on to my computer remotely and giving it a whack?  contactme@daleallen.com if you are interested....

Comment: If you want to redirect users from an old file to a new file AND your old file is a .asp file then there's one very simple thing you can do.  Just add <% Response.Redirect("http://insert-the-url-of-your-new-file-here") %> as the very first line of code in your old file.  The redirect location can be either an absolute URL(ie beginning with http) or a relative one  As Westie suggested above, we're here to help you write your own code, not to write it for you.  If you want me to work on your site then my contract rate is £30 (GBP)/hr